# How to tell to the compiler a function can only return subtype of a trait and not the trait itself?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

I am trying to write some code that takes an URL, get the content from this URL, and saves it. The method to get the content from an URL is specific to the website, but then the content extracted uses a common format and can be saved in a database for example.

So I first define a type representing each supported URL:

```
trait Url(url: String)

case class Soundcloud(url: String) extends Url(url)
case class Youtube(url: String) extends Url(url)
```

Then a method that given a string return the correct URL type:

```
def matchUrl(s: String): Option[Url] =
  val s_regex = "soundcloud.com".r
  var y_regex = "youtube.com".r
  s match
    case s_regex() => Some(Soundcloud(s))
    case y_regex() => Some(Youtube(s))
    case _         => None
```

Then I define a trait for the content extractors:

```
trait GetContent[T <: Url]:
  def get: Unit  // should actually return something like `Content`
```

Here is my method to save an URL's content in the db:

```
def save[T <: Url](t: T)(using gc: GetContent[T]) =
  gc.get
  // save into db
```

Then I provide two implementations of `GetContent`, one for each URL type:

```
given GetContent[Soundcloud] with
  def get = println("getting some content from soundcloud")

given GetContent[Youtube] with
  def get = println("getting some content from youtube")
```

And finally I can plug it all together:

```
matchUrl("youtube.com").map(r => save(r))
```

The compiler complains that

> no implicit argument of type GetContent[Url] was found for parameter gc of method save

If I call my method like this it works fine:

```
save(Soundcloud("http://soundcloud.com/some/content"))
```

I need to tell the compiler that `matchUrl` can only return an instance of `Soundcloud` or `Youtube`, never a `Url`.

Comment: You could make your own enum mimicking `Option` but with an extra field holding a `GetContent` implicit. It's highly unsatisfying, though (at least the way I ended up implementing it). [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uYwheNnRQfO2V7p2bPPpTg). (Interestingly, my Scastie revealed several bugs/implementation restrictions in the compiler regarding polymorphic functions. Looks like we'll have to wait for that to be polished)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problems is leveraging `transparent inline`.
Furthermore, if you want to tell that the method will eventually return a Soundcloud instance **or** a Youtube instance, you can use the union type `|`.

In this case, the compiler refines the return type with the subtype return:

```
transparent inline def matchUrl(s: String): Option[Soundcloud | Youtube] =
  inline s match
    // I use some regexs here for the real implementation
    case "soundcloud.com" => Some(Soundcloud(s))
    case "youtube.com"    => Some(Youtube(s))
    case _                => None
```

In this way, calling `matchUrl("soundcloud.com")` will return the refined type `Option[Soundcloud]` and then the compiler can find the implicit accordingly.

[Scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pnXIPaJ0SdynUfrcoqBnvA)

Comment: Ok this works with my example, because it seems the compiler can use static string to know which type the match will return. But my real use case uses regex, and the compiler cannot infer the match return type anymore.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that, I am sorry. Yes, this solution works only if the compiler *knows* what String did you pass at *compile-time*. If you use regex from a user input this cannot work...